# How do Renewing Action and Initiate of the Faith interact?

Tags: dnd-4e, multi-classing, paragon-path

The Cleric paragon path [Seldarine Dedicate](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/paragonpath.aspx?id=406)<sup>DDI</sup> action point feature Renewing Action states:

> **Renewing Action (11th level):** When you spend an action point to take an extra action, you also gain an extra use of your healing word power for this encounter.

How does this interact with the daily *Healing Word* usage granted by [Initiate of the Faith](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/feat.aspx?id=333)<sup>DDI</sup>?

To me, it seems that you could now use *Healing Word* once per day, plus once for each action point you spend. Is this assumption correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes**

There are no special restrictions on powers granted through multiclassing save for those orderly in the original mulitclass modification.

In contrast, the Barbarian's pseudo-rage, not being a power, is not recoverable save by extended rest.